# Why discrete Newton converges faster than ordinary Newton?

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, nonlinear-system

I am find solve for this system
$$
\begin{cases}
cosh(y) + 2x = 45\\
\dfrac{x^2}{5} - y^2 + 10x = 500
\end{cases}
$$
I use two Newton methods for solving. In first I get derivative value as analythical(i.e. just put the value in the calculated derivative) and in second(discrete Newton) I find derivative by definition(for example 
$f_x' = \dfrac{f(x, y) - f(x * (1 - eps), y)}{x * eps}$ ).

I give the algorithms the same initial approximations obtained graphically. Ordinary Newton converges about 120-150 iterations and discrete version converges in 3-4 iterations?

Why?

This is my code.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np


def f1():
    x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
    return sp.cosh(y) + 2 * x - 45


def f2():
    x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
    return x**2 / 5 - y**2 + 10 * x - 500


def f(cur_x):
    x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
    return f1().subs([(x, cur_x[0]), (y, cur_x[1])]), \
           f2().subs([(x, cur_x[0]), (y, cur_x[1])])


def newton(cur_x):
    x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
    next_x = (cur_x[0] + 1, cur_x[1] + 1)
    W = np.zeros(shape=(2, 2))
    cnt = 0
    while max(np.abs(next_x[0] - cur_x[0]), np.abs(next_x[1] - cur_x[1])) >= 1e-6:
        if cnt != 0:
            cur_x = next_x
        cnt += 1

        W[0][0] = sp.diff(f1(), x).subs([(x, cur_x[0]), (y, cur_x[1])])
        W[0][1] = sp.diff(f1(), y).subs([(x, cur_x[0]), (y, cur_x[1])])
        W[1][0] = sp.diff(f2(), x).subs([(x, cur_x[0]), (y, cur_x[1])])
        W[1][0] = sp.diff(f2(), y).subs([(x, cur_x[0]), (y, cur_x[1])])
        inv = np.linalg.inv(W)

        f_in_point = f(cur_x)
        next_x = cur_x - np.dot(inv, f_in_point)
        next_x[0] = next_x[0].evalf()
        next_x[1] = next_x[1].evalf()

    return next_x, cnt


def get_der(f, xy, ind=0):
    eps = 1e-6
    x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
    res = f.subs([(x, xy[0]), (y, xy[1])]).evalf()
    new = 0
    if ind == 0:
        new = f.subs([(x, xy[0] * (1 - eps)), (y, xy[1])]).evalf()
    else:
        new = f.subs([(x, xy[0]), (y, xy[1] * (1 - eps))]).evalf()
    return (res - new) / (xy[ind] * eps)


def discrete_newton(cur_x):
    next_x = (cur_x[0] + 1, cur_x[1] + 1)
    W = np.zeros(shape=(2, 2))
    cnt = 0
    while max(np.abs(next_x[0] - cur_x[0]), np.abs(next_x[1] - cur_x[1])) >= 1e-6:
        if cnt != 0:
            cur_x = next_x
        cnt += 1

        lst = [f1(), f2()]
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(2):
                W[i][j] = get_der(lst[i], cur_x, j)

        inv = np.linalg.inv(W)

        f_in_point = f(cur_x)
        next_x = cur_x - np.dot(inv, f_in_point)
        next_x[0] = next_x[0].evalf()
        next_x[1] = next_x[1].evalf()

    return next_x, cnt


def main():
    print('Newton start:')
    for x in [(-83, 6), (-82, -6)]:
        val, cnt = newton(x)
        print(val, cnt)
        print('f(x, y) = {}'.format(f(val)[0]))
    print('Newton end.')
    print('Discrete Newton start:')
    for x in [(-83, 6), (-82, -6)]:
        val, cnt = discrete_newton(x)
        print(val, cnt)
        print('f(x, y) = {}'.format(f(val)[1]))
    print('Discrete Newton end.')


main()
```

Comment: How does "discrete Newton" work ? And another question that comes in my mind : Why does "ordinary Newton" converge so slow in this case ?

Comment: What does ch mean? [Here's a MathJax guide.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Peter as I write I only found derivative by defenition.

Comment: @J.G., fix. It's $cosh$. Thank's for guide.

Comment: @dasfex your definition of derivative is not very convenient... What if $x=0$? You'd better use, for instance,  $$ f'_x \approx \dfrac{f(x,y) - f(x- eps , y)}{eps}.$$

Comment: Could you show us the code you used, especially for ordinary Newton? If you relied on a library, it may have converged slowly due to a poorly approximated Hessian, or a small gradient at the root that rapidly grows away from it, so that the first difference is much larger. Assessment of such hypotheses may be easier if you share the root.

Comment: @PierreCarre, I am choose first approximation so x can't be equal to zero.

Comment: @J.G., add code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains bugs. For example, your second `W[1][0]` should be `W[1][1]`. I'm also unclear why you add $1$ to each component of `cur_x` to create `next_x`, since the algorithm should only increment the iteration index.  Any conclusions you've drawn from your experiment regarding the convergence rate are therefore spurious.

Comment: I think that my matrix $W$ is right cause it may view like $F(x)$ in (5) formula: https://slemeshevsky.github.io/num-mmf/snes/html/._snes-FlatUI001.html
And I create '''next_x''' in this way cause I want to guarantee that I'm going inside while.

Comment: @dasfex I don't recommend doing in that way. If we summarize the iteration as $x\mapsto g(x)$ where the function $g$ has been refactored out, you can start with two variables, say `a` and `b = g(a)`, and then you can write `while max(np.abs(a-b))>1e-6: a, b = b, g(b)`.